# highest number in each row in a DF and return column of numbers

Tags: python, pandas, max

Hi I have a list of sock prices and calculated 5 moving averages

I want to find the max number in each ROW.  The code is returning the max number for the entire array

Here is the code

```
 # For stock in df:
      Create 10,30,50,100 and 200D MAvgs                             
      MA10D = stock.rolling(10).mean()
      MA30D = stock.rolling(30).mean()
      MA50D = stock.rolling(50).mean()
      MA100D = stock.rolling(100).mean()
      MA200D = stock.rolling(200).mean()
     max_line = pd.concat([MA10D, MA30D, MA50D, MA100D, MA200D],axis=0).max()
```

I want to create  new column with the max number (either the 10D, 30D, 50D, 100D or 200DMA).  So I should get a value on each row.

Right now all I get in the max number of the each entire array.  I tried axis=1 and that did not work either.

Seems like a simple question but I can not get it written properly.  Please let me know if you can help.  thanks

Comment: "did not work either" - how exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `axis=0` in your code refers to the concatenation.  You need to make that `axis=1` to make each moving average a separate column.  ***Then*** use `axis=1` in your call to `max` ***as well***.  It should look like this.

```
max_line = pd.concat([MA10D, MA30D, MA50D, MA100D, MA200D], axis=1).max(1)
```